# How to concatenate jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### $.and?

so I have a var that containssome jquery object which contains some elements (in this case <a> elements)

```
var elements = $('a');
```

I then want to add some other elements (in this case <b> elements) to this string when using a click function for instance...

```
elements.and('b').on("click", function(){
    //some random code
});
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) ?

```
elements.add('b')....
```

Note that `$('a, b');` would do too.

Comment: Bingo! So hard to find a function like this when the only keywords I can think to use is jquery and "and". Will mark as correct in about 6 minutes